# Which python deep learning libraries compile at runtime?

Tags: python, compilation, runtime, pytorch, theano

I am trying to wrap my head around C-optimized code in python. I have read a couple of times now that python achieves high-speed computing through C-extensions. In other words, whenever I work with libraries such as numpy, it basically calls a C-extension that calculates the result and returns it.

#### C-extensions using numpy

Say I want to add two numbers using `np.add(x,y)`. If I understand it correctly, libraries such as numpy do not compile the python code but instead already come with executables that will simply take the values x and y and return the result. Is that correct?

#### Theano, Tensorflow, and PyTorch

In particular, I am wondering if this is also true for deep learning libraries. According to the official documentation of Theano, it requires g++ and gcc (at least they are highly recommended). Does this mean that Theano will compile C (or C++) code **at runtime** of the python script? If so, is it the same for PyTorch and Tensorflow?

I hope that someone can solve my confusion here! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C extensions in python**

`numpy` uses C-extensions a lot. For instance, you can take a look at the C implementation of the sort() function [1] here [2].

[1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

[2] https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c.src

**Deep learning libraries**

Deep learning libraries use C-extensions for a large part of their backend, as well as CUDA and CUDNN. Code can be compiled at runtime:

[3] http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/pipeline.html#compilation-of-the-computation-graph

[4] https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/jit

[5] https://pytorch.org/blog/the-road-to-1_0/#production--pain-for-researchers

To answer your question, `theano` will compile C/C++ code at runtime of the python script. The graph compilation time at runtime is extremely slow for `theano`: I advise you to focus on `pytorch` or `tensorflow` rather than `theano`.

If you're new to deep learning, you may take a quick look at [6] too.

[6] https://github.com/google/jax

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot! Does that mean that PyTorch or Tensorflow do not compile the code at runtime at all? Or just that the graph compilation is much faster?

Comment: All of them compile some code at runtime : see page 60: https://indico.cern.ch/event/708041/contributions/3308814/attachments/1813852/2963725/automatic_differentiation_and_deep_learning.pdf

Comment: Regarding theano graph compilation time, my answer is solely based on my personal experience. I could not find any **recent** benchmark that include theano and other DL libraries on the web, though. Keep in mind that theano development is stopped since 2017: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/7Poq8BZutbY

Comment: See page12: https://project.inria.fr/deeplearning/files/2016/05/DLFrameworks.pdf it also says that "[theano] compile time of big models can be a huge pain"